# Can I change the priority of a process in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, scheduling

I understand from here http://cs.ucsb.edu/~puneet/reports/erlang.pdf (section 4.4) that Process Scheduling in Erlang is based on 4 different queues - with one designated as 'highest priority'. I have an Erlang program and I'd like to assign one process so that its instructions join this queue. Is there a way to do this? Are there any watch-its when doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check Erlang's doc [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_flag-2). There is a BIF called `process_flag(Flag, Option)`.

```
process_flag(priority, Level)
% This sets the process priority. Level is an atom. 
% There are currently four priority levels: low, normal, high, and max. 
% The default is normal.
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing that you use this function just before you spawn the process? Or do you put it in the function you spawn?

Comment: @atomh33ls see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381036/what-is-the-correct-use-of-process-flagpriority-level-in-erlang). And if you want to change priority outside, there's process_flag/3