# What is the correct use of process_flag(priority, Level) in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, scheduling

I want to use the process_flag(priority, Level) to set the priority of a process. I am a little confused as to where it should go in my code and can't seem to find an example.

The two options that I can see are:

(1) Set the flag before spawning the process:

```
process_flag(priority, max),
register(myprocess, spawn(fun() -> myprocess() end)),
```

(2) Set the flag within the function after it has been spawned:

```
myprocess() ->
process_flag(priority, max),
%do stuff
```

Also, if option 1 is correct, do I need to reset the flag to `normal` before spawning other processes?

Comment: You don't **really** want to use process priorities. As @legoscia points out don't use `max`, it effectively blocks that scheduler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 2 is the correct one.  As the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_flag-2) says, `process_flag/2` "sets certain flags for the process which calls this function".  I don't think any of the process flags are inherited to spawned processes.

The documentation also suggests not using the `max` priority level:

> The `max` priority level is reserved for internal use in the Erlang runtime system, and should *not* be used by others.